# How do you add up the value of Hebrew letters with spaces in map in C++?

Tags: c++, maps

I'm trying to make a [Gematria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gematria) calculator in C++ and I'm almost there; however, when I put in multiple words, meaning there are spaces, it only gives me the gematria of the first word.

How would I make it so it includes the spaces?

Here's my code:

```
int main() {
std::unordered_map <char, double > Gematria_Values = {
{' ', 0}
{'א', 1},
{'ב',  2},
// Goes through rest of hebrew alphabet.
};
// Creates string Gematria
std::string Gematria;
std::cout << "What do you want the gematria of ?" << std::endl;
// Stores input as Gematria
std::cin >> Gematria;
int sum = 0;
for (auto ch : Gematria)
sum += Gematria_Values[ch];
std::cout << "The Gematria of " << Gematria << " is " << sum;
return 0;
```

So, when I enter "אאאבב" (without the quotes), I get:

```
The Gematria of אאאבב is 7
```

However, when I enter אאא בב I get:

```
The gematria of אאא is 3
```

So, even though I have a space that = 0, it doesn't add up with the words. So how would I get it so it adds up with the spaces, so it could add up more than one word at a time?

A side question is how do I get it so I don't get the error message of :

```
Character too large for enclosing character literal type
```

It would also be nice to know how to break this up into a few methods, but again that's just a side point. My main question is how do I add the Gematria with the spaces?

Answer (score 0):

You should access the map elements using map->first and map->second.
so, in your case, I'd do something like:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::unordered_map <char, double > Gematria_Values = {
    {' ', 0},
    {'a', 1},
    {'b' , 2},
    // Goes through rest of hebrew alphabet.
    };
    // Creates string Gematria
    std::string Gematria;
    std::cout << "What do you want the gematria of ?" << std::endl;
    // Stores input as Gematria
    getline(std::cin, Gematria);
    int sum = 0;
    for (auto ch : Gematria)
        sum += Gematria_Values.find(ch)->second;
    std::cout << "The Gematria of " << Gematria << " is " << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I changed it to your answer, and now it doesn't give me the gematria at all, it just prints back the hebrew that I inputted. Mhm.

Comment: Input will still stop at the first whitespace.

Comment: @AdrianMole, That's right, I overlooked. using getline to get the user input is a great idea for this.

Comment: @django, I want you to try sum += Gematria_Values.find(ch)->first; and see the result

Comment: @Prashanthv would I be keeping as wchar_t, and wcout etc? Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Mhm, I still get the same result as before, in other words it prints out "The gematria of  is 0."

Comment: @django, could be encoding problem. I just tried the following with english alphabet and it worked for me. I have edited my answer to reflect the full working code.

Comment: Note that the `[]` operator on a `std::map` does the key->value translation (assuming the key exists).

Comment: @AdrianMole, noted!.

Answer (score 0):

The `>>` (input) operation for a `std::string` type ends when a whitespace is found in the input stream. Thus, your attempted input (אאא בב) is only reading the first three characters.

You can read in the entire line (up to, but not including, the terminating newline) using the [`std::getline()` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) with `std::cin` as the first (stream) argument.

---

> A side question is how do I get it so I don't get the error message of
> `Character too large for enclosing character literal type`.

You can use the *wide* character-based versions of `cout`, `cin` and `string`, and also make your map use `wchar_t` in place of `char`.

Here's a possible solution:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map <wchar_t, int> Gematria_Values = { // Not sure why you used "double" here but "int" for the sum...
        {L' ', 0},
        {L'‭א', 1}, // Note: There is an invisible character before the Hebrew
        {L'‭ב', 2}, // letters in these lines (to force left-to-right override).
        // Goes through rest of hebrew alphabet.
    };
    // Creates string Gematria
    std::wstring Gematria;
    std::wcout << "What do you want the gematria of ?" << std::endl;
    // Stores input as Gematria
//  std::wcin >> Gematria;
    std::getline(std::wcin, Gematria);
    int sum = 0;
    for (auto ch : Gematria)
        sum += Gematria_Values[ch];
    std::wcout << L"The Gematria of " << Gematria << L" is " << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

I can't *fully* test it on my platform, as my console doesn't properly process Hebrew characters – please feel free to let me know if there are issues in this respect. However, a test after replacing the `א` and `ב` with `a` and `b` suggests it works well.

Comment: Mhm, so I changed the code to this, and it's a little better then the first answer, and I'm not getting a error anymore, however it doesn't print the Hebrew words, it just prints "The gematria of  is 0." It doesn't show the hebrew input, so it just shows it as 0.

Comment: @django Can you try using a Latin alphabet test? Possibly an issue with the console locale mode, or something similar.

Comment: @django You could also try reverting to the 'normal' `string`, `cin` and `cout` (rather than the 'w' versions) but keeping the key value as a `wchar_t` type. Non-ASCII character I/O can be troublesome.

Comment: So I took your advice and now when i enter says "דד גג" (without the quotes), I get The Gematria of דד גג is 0, so now it's showing the hebrew but not adding up at all.

Comment: would changing the for loop work, in other words should I try doing something like for (int i = 0, i < Gematria.length() i++) {sum += Gematria_Values.get(String.valueof(Letters.charAt(i)))} That's what I did for this same type of thing in Java, and am just trying to apply the same thing to C++, but it gets so complicated dealing with unicode or whatever.

Comment: @django So, what happens if you revert to your *original* code (which *almost* worked) and just use `getline()` in place of the `cin >>` line? Try that with the test you showed in your question: we can then maybe see where the encoding issue is occurring.

Comment: I just changed it back to my _original_ code and did `std::getline(std::cin, Gematria)` instead of `std::cin >> Gematria` and now it works although i'm getting the Character too large for enclosing character literal type message, but it still works @AdrianMole Thank you so much

Comment: @django Cool. You can now try making the *single* change of using the `wchar_t` type for your map key. Sounds like a good Unicode-exploration exercise. :-)

Comment: When I do that single change then it shows the hebrew words, but no gematria lol.