# How to properly call functions?

Tags: c++, function

I'm working on my [gematria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gematria) project that I was asking about [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67258131/how-do-you-add-up-the-value-of-hebrew-letters-with-spaces-in-map-in-c) and I managed to fix my main issue there, however I'm trying to break the program down into methods, and I'm getting a error with it and am having trouble figuring out how to fix it.
Here is my current code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<string>
void PrintGematria(){
std::string Gematria = std::string AskGematria()
    if(!Gematria.empty()){
      std::cout << "The gematria of " << Gematria << " is " << int ConvertLetters(Gematria);
      PrintGematria();
     }
     else {
         std::cout << "Hope you enjoyed\n";
        }
}

[[maybe_unused]] std::string AskGematria(){
   std::cout << "What do you want the gematria of?\n";
   std::string Gematria;
   std::getline(std::cin, Gematria);
   return Gematria;
}

[[maybe_unused] int ConvertLetters(const std::string& Letters){
//Converts letters to numerical value.
std::unordered_map <char, double> Gematria_Values = {
      {' ', 0},
      {'א', 1},
      {'ב',  2},
      {'ג', 3},
//Goes through rest of hebrew alphabet. 
};
int sum = 0;
for (auto ch : Letters)
    sum += Gematria_Values[ch]
return sum;
}

int main() {
//Gives the Value to the user. 
PrintGematria();
return 0;
```

So at the end in my main method when I reference PrintGematria(), it seems to be fine, however in my PrintGematria() method itself I'm getting an error when calling AskGematria() and when calling ConvertLetters(Gematria), it says about both of those methods
Expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction.
The thing is that when I try

```
void PrintGematria(){
std::string Gematria = std::string (AskGematria());
       if(!Gematria.empty()){
           std::cout << "The gematria of " << Gematria << " is " << int (ConvertLetters(Gematria));
           PrintGematria();
       }
       else {
           std::cout << "Hope you enjoyed\n";
       }
```

I also get a error albiet here it just shows the red and doesn't say what to do there.
So ultimately I want to know how do I properly call the methods in this case?

Comment: `PrintGematria()` calls `PrintGematria()`? Is that intended?

Comment: Yes, that way the function loops in itself and repeats until the user just presses the space bar with no input (although would be nice to do something like if input is a key in unordered_map then ConvertLetters(Gematria), and if not then wrong input and like entering a number, or nothing to stop program.

Comment: You need to have a declaration of a function before you use it. So somewhere before `PrintGematria`, you need to provide at least signatures for `AskGematria` and `ConvertLetters`.

Comment: revisit your code!!! unbalanced parentasises and a lot of probelms.

Comment: Don't use recursion for iteration. Use iteration for iteration. Recursion is for cases when you want to stack a context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your function call.

1. You are attempting to call a function before it has been declared / defined. Either move AskGematria above PrintGematria or add a prototype declaration for AskGematria ahead of PrintGematria:

   ```
    std::string AskGematria();
   ```
2. The proper way to call the function is `std::string Gematria = AskGematria();`. You don't need to put `std::string` before the function call.